# How do I export a recurring csv from gmail to my gdrive

Tags: google-apps-script

I get a csv file daily and I want to replace the existing file in my gdrive with this new file.Please help

Comment: I think that when you provide your latest script, it will help users think of your solution.

Comment: I have a gscript which transfers only 10K rows from my gmail csv to a google sheet  in 30 mins after which it times out. So I have to manually copy the csv and paste it to google sheet.          Also I have found that if I transfer from an existing gsheet to my new gsheet it takes 1 min to transfer the whole file that is 100K rows. So I want a script so that I can directly transfer the csv in my gmail to a prespecified  gsheet in my gdrive.